# Tangent Line Length At Top Of Inside Circle

Tags: triangles, circles

[Question In Picture Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL3hb.png)

From the picture, r is known and θ is known.  I am trying to find the length of line X.  The circle is tangent to the two lines of the triangle and the triangle is isosceles.  Is there any other information I need to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.  Everything I found during research is for a fully inscribed circle.

Comment: Note that by your assumptions the point where $\theta$ is, point of tangency and the centre of the circle are collinear.  This line is the bisector of $\theta$ and is normal to the red line. Then note two similar triangles and use trigonometry.

Comment: Use the formual $$r=\frac{\Delta}{s-a}$$ where $\Delta$ denotes the area of the given triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let 
$|AB|=x$,
$|AC|=|BC|=a$
and $S$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Then the circle is the excircle of $\triangle ABC$,
for which it is known that its radius
\begin{align}
r_c&=\frac{2S}{|AC|+|BC|-|AB|}
=\frac{2S}{2a-x}
,\\
S&=\tfrac12a^2\sin\theta
,\\
a&=\frac{x}{2\sin\tfrac\theta2}
,\\
\end{align}

and after simplifications, we can find $x$ as
\begin{align} 
x&=\frac{2r_c(1-\sin\tfrac\theta2)}{\cos\tfrac\theta2}
.
\end{align}

**Edit**

Or, we can get the same result just from

\begin{align} 
r_c=
|CO_t|\sin\tfrac\theta2
&=
(|CC_t|+r_c)\sin\tfrac\theta2
\\
&=
(\tfrac{x}2\cot\tfrac\theta2+r_c)\sin\tfrac\theta2
.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you!  this worked great!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming that $BB' \perp OC$

we have

$$
\phi = \angle{AOC} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}
$$

hence

$$
x = 2 r \tan\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)
$$